# Just Cause 2 lost game

Tags: just-cause-2

After 36 hours progress on Just Cause 2 - I got stuck, so I started a new game. It warned that this would overwrite autosave data but I went ahead and started a new game - does this mean I have totally lost the old game - all that 36 hours progress? Is there any way to bring that old game back - I mean surely the PS3 saves a certain amount of the progress somewhere? Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Did the auto save function kick in during the "new game"? If so I'm afraid its lost.

The way saved games are handled in Just Cause 2 is that you are expected to save regularly to ensure progress isn't lost. The auto save only takes up one "slot" and is rewritten frequently.

It's actually more of a safety net against random deaths or errors than a long term way to save your game.

Answer (score 4):

You should always save your game manually trough the menu, so whenever you start a new game and your auto-save file is overwritten, you will be able to load it back up using one of your 10(or so) custom save slots.

For those on the pc: The save files are located in your documents folder under the name 'square enix/just cause 2/', you might get previous versions back from there if windows automatically saves recent states of that folder.

Good luck re-doing stuff.

though 36 hours isn't much time lost relatively speaking, it took me about 60 hours of gameplay to finish ALL locations AND challenges.

Comment: I don't see how you could reasonably think that "36 hours isn't much time lost". That's a day and a half of playing the game straight, and longer than playing through an awful lot of other games. If I lost 36 hours of progress on a game I don't think I'd be redoing it.

Comment: note that I said it isn't much time lost RELATIVELY speaking. since going for the full completion takes about the double amount of time. You can compare it to school, it takes one year to finish a semester. If you fail and have to redo a year, a full year of work is actually lost so you'll have to redo it. But 1 year is once again, nothing compared to the full 4 semesters to finish the education. But it's totally up to you whether you actually find the will power to redo it.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is not much that can be done.